# Redirect after cookie validation fails in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core

I have implemented a cookie validator as described in the [ASP.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore1x):

```
public static class CookieValidator
{
    public static async Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        ...

        if (invalidCookie)
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await context.HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("MyCookieScheme");
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be working correctly and gets into the `invalidCookie` block, rejecting the principal and signing out.  After that I would like to redirect to a different URL.  How do I have it redirect if I invalidate the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

It should already return a 302 and add a 'location' header to your response with either the 'AccessDeniedPath' or 'LoginPath' when you reject principal, however lets say you want to add a header change the status code, or other customization.

In the invalidCookie block you can set custom headers with the following.

```
context.httpContext.Response.Headers["forceRedirect"] = httpContext.Request.Host.ToString();
```

Then when you get the response back on the client you need to check if this header is present, if it is then you redirect to the link given. This allows you to at least set headers, however if you changed the status code in the same place the framework will still override the status code when you reject principal (after you are out of the ValidateAsync function).

In order to do this, and stop the framework from overriding your custom response you have to declare an onRedirectToAccessDenied funtion.

In startup.cs: ConfigureServices

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => { //this just makes checks against the cookie, so if the user deletes the cookie then ValidateAsync never fires
            // Cookie settings ...
            options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = CookieValidator.overrideRedirect;
            options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = CookieValidator.ValidateAsync;
        });
```

Then in CookieValidator:

It is worth noting that if you do this then other rejections will execute this code too. Like if you also have a Roles authorization then when the user fails that authorization it will call this. This can be frustrating if you want the code to return different responses based upon why auth failedI am solving this by using policies and having them return the custom responses because it knows exactly why it failed then have overrideRedirect empty so the framework doesn't change my response.

```
internal static async Task overrideRedirect(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context) {
        ...
        //In here you can customize the response anyway you want and it will not be changed
    }
```

It should be noted that ValidateAsync only is called if the cookie is present in the request, so if the user deletes the cookie then they can skip this validation. In my case I got around this by validating the cookie here, but still had other auth code (i added policy requirements in an IAuthorizationHandler) later that verified that the user had a claim. If the user deleted their cookie then the claim wouldn't be there and they would still lose access.